# python __class__ not inherited?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Python3 test is

```
class My(object):
    def whoami():
        print(__class__)

class My2(My):
    pass

My.whoami()
My2.whoami()
```

output is

```
<class '__main__.My'>
<class '__main__.My'>
```

I would like

```
<class '__main__.My'>
<class '__main__.My2'>
```

where am i wrong please?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but since the method `whoami` is defined in the `My` class, it will always report `My`, even if called from a subclass like `My2` which inherits from `My`

Comment: Are you intentionally using `__class__` instead of `self.__class__`  and instances? You could solve this with a classmethod, perhaps.

Comment: @sytech : yes, I really want __class__ and not with an instance of any object ...
I don't want to use self ... as I need a static function

Comment: `__class__` is a special closure used to implement the zero-argument form of `super`. Roughly speaking, its value is fixed when the method is defined, not looked up when the method is called.

Comment: So using a static method makes no sense, but it will work with a class method as you can see in the answer from @sytech.

Comment: @chepner Well I learned something new today! That's good info.

Answer (score 4):

If you meant for these to be methods called directly on the class (without an instance), you can use a classmethod:

```py
class My:
    @classmethod
    def whoami(cls):
        print(cls)

class My2(My):
    pass

My.whoami()
My2.whoami()
```

```
<class '__main__.My'>
<class '__main__.My2'>
```